# Anacondaをインストールし、Tensorflowを使って機械学習をしたいのですが、Permission deniedとエラーが出てインストールできません。

Tags: python, python3, tensorflow, anaconda

#### 前提・実現したいこと

画像認識の機械学習のモデルを勉強したいため、Anacondaをインストールし、TensorflowやKerasを用いて自分なりに勉強したいと思っています。
そのため、Python 3.6 versionのmac用のAnaconda 5.1をインストールし、コマンドプロンプトから実行しました。機械学習や環境構築を含むプログラミングに関しては初心者で、開発経験などもございません。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

どうも私のPCだと解凍処理やインストールで[permission denied]というエラーメッセージが多発し、コマンドを受け付けないことが多いです。
アナコンダをインストールしようと、シェル上で
bash /Users/keisuke/Downloads/code/Anaconda3-5.1.0-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
を打つと、インストールを開始しますが途中で解凍の許可が下りずに止まってしまいます。以下がエラー内容です。

> installing: python-3.6.4-hc167b69_1 ...
>   Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.
>   installing: bzip2-1.0.6-hd86a083_4 ...
>   installing: ca-certificates-2017.08.26-ha1e5d58_0 ...
>   installing: conda-env-2.6.0-h36134e3_0 ...
>   installing: intel-openmp-2018.0.0-h8158457_8 ...
>   installing: jbig-2.1-h4d881f8_0 ...
>   installing: jpeg-9b-he5867d9_2 ...
>   installing: libcxxabi-4.0.1-hebd6815_0 ...
>   installing: libgfortran-3.0.1-h93005f0_2 ...
>   installing: libiconv-1.15-hdd342a3_7 ...
>   installing: libsodium-1.0.15-hd9e47c5_0 ...
>   installing: lzo-2.10-h362108e_2 ...
>   installing: pandoc-1.19.2.1-ha5e8f32_1 ...
>   **bunzip2: Can't open input file /Users/keisuke/anaconda3/pkgs/pandoc-1.19.2.1-ha5e8f32_1.tar.bz2: Permission denied.**
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/keisuke/anaconda3/pkgs/.install.py", line 618, in 
>       main2()
>     File "/Users/keisuke/anaconda3/pkgs/.install.py", line 599, in main2
>       link_dist(opts.link_dist)
>     File "/Users/keisuke/anaconda3/pkgs/.install.py", line 454, in link_dist
>       link(prefix, dist, linktype)
>     File "/Users/keisuke/anaconda3/pkgs/.install.py", line 328, in link
>       files = list(yield_lines(join(info_dir, 'files')))
>     File "/Users/keisuke/anaconda3/pkgs/.install.py", line 96, in yield_lines
>       for line in open(path):
>   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/keisuke/anaconda3/pkgs/pandoc-1.19.2.1-ha5e8f32_1/info/files'

このほかにもpip install tensorflowと打つと、

> Collecting tensorflow
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/1e/d89f1369b5b8045e5aedf43718b45d2396d3c61e9cc56123c24b7758dd9f/tensorflow-1.8.0-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl
>   **Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:** u'/private/var/folders/4y/z038tqx15jvfqptw0s_tmz8w0000gp/T/pip-unpack-Sk9pwB/tensorflow-1.8.0-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl'
>   Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

のように[permission denied]と出ていずれにせよTensorflowをインストールできません。

#### 試したこと

エラーメッセージを頼りに様々な解説サイトを参考にして以下のような方法を試しましたが全てダメでした。
・sudoや--userをつけたり、umaskを緩く設定してコードを実行　→　同じエラー
・python関係の全てのフォルダ/ファイルを削除してanacondaを再インストール　→　同じエラー
・anaconda navigatorを使ってtensorflowをインストールしようとする　→　ロードした後何も追加されずに終わる（おそらく裏でpermission deniedが起こってます）
・(env)(tonsorflow)$　のように、tensorflowの仮想環境に入って同じことを実行　→　同じエラー

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

今の条件：
・Macbook Pro 10.12.6（品質の良い中古品）
・echo $PATH
/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
・.bash_profile
export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
・Python 2.7.15
・/Users/keisukeと、/Users/keisuke/Downloads/codeの下に「anaconda3」という同じファイルが入っています（中身は違う）。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://qiita.com/gonta32/items/0c373210f4b870af1b02

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/128277

Answer (score 2):

質問については、以下のエラーが出ているので、
`bunzip2: Can't open input file /Users/keisuke/anaconda3/pkgs/pandoc-1.19.2.1-ha5e8f32_1.tar.bz2: Permission denied.`

次ののコマンドで該当ファイルの所有者とパーミッションを調べて、適正なものに修正してみてください。

```
ls -l ~/anaconda3/pkgs/pandoc-1.19.2.1-ha5e8f32_1.tar.bz2
```

また、以下のコマンドで解凍できるか確認してみてください。

```
bunzip2 ~/anaconda3/pkgs/pandoc-1.19.2.1-ha5e8f32_1.tar.bz2
```

質問の後半の`pip install tensorflow`に対して、`Permission denied`のエラーが発生するのは正常です。Anaconda のインストールができていない状況なので、pip はMacのシステムでインストールされているpython2.7へのパッケージをインストールする操作になります。その場合は、root権限が必要になります。なお、`sudo pip install tensorflow`とするのは、Macのシステムを変更することになるのであまり適切なことではありません。

試したことに「sudoをつけてコードを実行してみた」とありますが、Anacondaをホームディレクトリにsudoでインストールするとホームディレクトリ内のドットファイルの方にもrootが所有者であるディレクトリやファイルができてしまいます。そうなると[permission denied]というエラーメッセージが多発しても当然のことです。まず、どういう場合にsudoが必要になるのか、homeディレクトリ内のディレクトリやファイルの所有者を自分にするというシェルの基本から学習したらどうでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。前半のご回答ですが、sudo pip install tensorflowを行うことでpython2.7にtensorflowを入れることができました。ただデフォルトのpythonに強制的にインストールするのは嫌なので、pip3で行いたいのですが、これはsudoで行ってもPermission deniedがまた出ます。

Comment: ちなみにpip3はこちらのディレクトリに入っています。：
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages　
　
　後半のご回答についてですが、確かにホームディレクトリにanaconda3のディレクトリが生成されましたが、確認したところ管理者はrootではなく、作業ユーザーでした。anacondaをインストールする際、.tar.bz2解凍がなされていないのはこの「管理者」が問題でしょうか？

Comment: 所有者と権限の問題があるので、ホームディレクトリで次のコマンドを実行してみたらどうですか。ドットファイルのことも注意してください。  

`sudo chown -R keisuke:keisuke .`  

`chmod -R u+rw .`

Comment: ディレクトリの実行権限（アクセス権）もつけないといけないかも。 `chmod -R u+X .`

Comment: もともとエラーが出ているファイルが所有者権限で、グループ(staff)に所有者が入っているので、グループ名も所有者にしても意味がないように思います。。また、rwx全て許可すると確かにエラーが出ずにインストールできると思いますが、第三者が編集できるというリスクが大きいので今回は遠慮させていただきます。結局このPermission deniedが出てanacondaがインストールできない根本の理由がまだわかりません。　ご回答ありがとうございました！

Comment: linuxの場合を書いてしましました。Macの場合は`sudo chown -R keisuke:staff .`ですね。